# How do I get the Love Balls?

Tags: pokemon-diamond-pearl-remakes

I'm playing Shining Pearl and my girlfriend gave me a Ralts egg in a Love ball, but I can only find Poke Balls, Ultra Balls, Great Balls, Dusk Balls and some others from the shops. Who do I talk to for trading for the Love Balls? I also could not find a trader for them in the underground sphere area.

Here is a picture of it in the status menu:
[image: picture of pokemon ball in status menu. ball is pink on top and white on the bottom. the top has a white heart outline and a vertical line in the middle]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot ?There is no such thing heart ball. Maybe it’s heal ball?

Comment: @Wondercricket I'll see if I can move a screenshot to my computer. It's not the heal ball. It has pink on top with a pink heart and white on the bottom without any pattern on the bottom.

Comment: @Wondercricket I was able to get a picture of the heart ball in the status menu and added it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pokéball your Raltz is in is known as the [Love Ball](https://www.serebii.net/itemdex/loveball.shtml).

Based on various guides, the Love Ball does not appear to be obtainable from any vendor within the game. The Love Ball was a pre-order bonus by pre-ordering the game through various vendors in the US and the UK, and redeemable codes in Japan.

Comment: Oh so it's a special mystery gift code item? How many of them are there, or is it just one for everybody who preorders it?

Comment: @temp it’s generally one per person who pre-orders it. For example, since it pre-ordered the game directly through the Switch, I received a quick ball pre-order bonus. Since the Japan one was from 7/11, you might see if you could post on a community site to see if some one can snag one for you (my friend did this for Shiny Zamazenta in sword and shield)

Comment: Oh she did the double pack preorder so I guess that's why. I feel bad for taking the special item so I'll need to make up for it somehow.

Comment: Meanwhile in Italy we get an amazing 10x Quick balls preorder bonus...

Comment: @pinckerman [And there was much rejoicing...](https://c.tenor.com/QE42hcsZjI4AAAAC/monty-python-rejoice.gif)